# Convert my blocked blog into an unblocked website

Tags: web, blogs, blogger, adsense

I am writing blog from last 4-5 years, but some how google has blocked adsense in my blog.
I have filled appeal form but it is also rejected.

If I convert my blog into a website through "Setting" options in blog setting then will those adsense will be unblocked or it will be blocked even after converting it into website ?

Comment: What caused the account suspension?

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question to the official Adsense support.

**Here:** https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense